# Why is SRII a gray market stock and isn't it moving up or down?

Tags: stocks

When I invested, it was a new company. The company is still viable and growing, why isn't the stock moving? What is grey market?

Comment: Are you referring to Speaking Roses International Inc., traded OTC as https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/srii?

Comment: As for what a grey market is, Google is your friend.

Comment: When did you invest? Looks like it [removed itself from the exchanges](https://sec.report/Document/0001096906-07-000953/) back in 2007.

Answer (score 1):

The gray/grey market is an unofficial market for securities  that have been suspended from exchange trading  or for new securities that  have not begun trading on an exchange.